# Connecting to an existing database - node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, api

I want to develop an API in Node.JS with only one endpoint taking 2 parameters : a number and a datetime.
This endpoint will return the result of a request in a MySql database, in json.

But my problem is : I don't know if I need to define the models in my code. Indeed, my database is already created, I am connected to it and I only need to return the result of one SQL request with the 2 parameters.

According to me, I think there would be a solution to just call the database and directly return the result.

Is it possible ?

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly the issue, but from the looks of it, maybe you are bound to some kind of ORM. In any case, most ORMs or the underlying database drivers allow you to send raw SQL queries to the MySQL server without the need for any kind of models or schemas.

For instance, using the *mysql* package from npm (sample taken from the official [repo](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction)):

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: Yes this is the good answer, I was not sure if this was working or not without defining the models. Thank you!!